# How to convert hover function with on in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$("td").hover(function(){
                $(this).find('a.btn').show();
                }, function(){
                $(this).find('a.btn').hide();
            })
```

How can i convert this function for new dom elements with `on`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#mytable").on('hover', 'td', function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').show();
    }, function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').hide();
});
```

But using the `'hover'` pseudo event as a substitute for passing `'mouseenter mouseleave'` is deprecated, so you should really use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` directly.

```
$("#mytable").on('mouseenter', 'td', function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').show();
})
.on('mouseleave', 'td', function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').hide();
});
```

Or like this:

```
$("#mytable").on({'mouseenter': function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').show();
}, 'mouseleave': function(){
    $(this).find('a.btn').hide();
}}, 'td');
```

Or shorter like this:

```
$("#mytable").on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'td', function(e){
    $(this).find('a.btn').toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Comment: @ianpgall: According to the docs for `.on()`: *"Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave"."* But then it does go on to describe passing a single event handler, so true to form, the docs seem unclear to me if it's just when passing a single handler that `'hover'` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was thinking of the main `.hover` method, not for use with `.on`. Well that's good to know at least!

Comment: @ianpgall: Easy mistake. I think I'll clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
$('td').on({
  mouseenter: function() { $(this).find('a.btn').show() }
  mouseleave: function() { $(this).find('a.btn').hide() }
})
```

**Edit:** It's not clear by your question if you need delegation in that case check out the other answer.